# Добавить запись, если её нет и удалить, если она есть

Tags: php, mysql

Можно ли как-то одним запросом провернуть такой "Toggle"? Или все же лучше делать это несколькими запросами?

Структура таблицы такая:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
    `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `group_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `time` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    KEY `user_group_id` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';
```

Comment: Вопрос: зачем ?

Comment: В MySQL одним невозможно. Разве что хранимой процедурой но внутри будут те же 2 действия

Comment: Делаете delete, если обработано 0 записей (запрос всегда возвращает сколько обработал, это доступно во всех языках) - то делаете insert